# Pymssql trouble on python 3.5 (Anaconda Package): Dll Load Failed: The Specific Module could not be found

Tags: python, sql, python-3.x, pymssql

I am having some issues importing pymssql. I installed it via PIP and I am using python 3.5 (anaconda package) on a win7 machine. I downloaded the appropriate DLL'S recommended here :

[http://www.pymssql.org/en/latest/freetds.html#windows][1]

and placed them in a folder called FreeTDS (in the same location anaconda installed in) and appended this to my python path and also added it to my windows path. But I am still not able to access this module. Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Try adding the folder containing the required FreeTDS DLLs to your Windows `PATH` (not `PYTHONPATH`) and see if that helps.

Comment: Tried that but no change... very strange

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This worked for me: [pymssql binaries maintained by Christoph Gohlke (UCI)](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pymssql) 
I ended up just uninstalling anaconda (python 3.5), doing a clean install and doing a pip install on the 64bit .whl provided in the link above. Worked like a charm (so far)

Comment: the wheel package worked for me by using `pip install <wheelfile>` on the normal Anaconda installation, where a normal `pip install pymssql` does not seem to work (DLL could not be found)

Comment: I didn't install PYMSSQL via pip.. I used the pymssql provided in the link above. I was having the exact issue but the package provided in the link worked fine.

Comment: E.G. download one of the packages (the appropriate one for your version).. this file will have the name pymssql-2.1.2-cp35-etc.whl.. open up a cmd window and do: pip install 2.1.2-cp35-etc.whl. (assuming you are in the correct place) The package will download and you will be good to go.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, but I resolved it by using:

```
conda install -c prometeia pymssql=2.1.0
```

Comment: @megadarkfriend no, the version in anaconda is for python 2.7 only.